# Anything better than Script Encoder for protecting code?

Tags: asp.net

Microsoft recommends their Script Encoder to encode asp.net scripts on server side from nosy/prying hosts. However according to this:

http://www.aspheute.com/english/20011123.asp

Its not very good. Are there any good, recommended ways which are very difficult to hack, or any free, easy to use obfuscation tools?

Comment: Ideally for C# console apps I mean, like executable .exe files, made in .net, any way to encode them or obfuscate for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script Encoder is for VBScript and other scripting technologies, which is what ***classic ASP*** is based on, not Asp.Net.

To protect .Net code is a different animal, as it all compiles down to MSIL, which can be decompiled pretty easily.  There are some obfuscates that you can use, but rather than give you a short, incomplete answer, I am going to recommend that you read the following article.  it's short, and has some links at the end for obfuscates.

https://web.archive.org/web/20210802164013/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/080404-1.aspx